# IPtables command shows libipt_random.so missing

Tags: linux, iptables

When I run a command, it shows error. I searched on net, but no one give me the correct answer. Googling shows only wrong answers for this questions.

So please help me to overcome this problem.

**Command**

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m random --average 50 -j DROP
```

**Error**

```
iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load match `random':/lib64/iptables/libipt_random.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Tell me link of file or any necessary changes that I have to do , to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind reply.

**EDIT NO. 1**
I followed the given link [iptables - see random patch](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `libipt_XXX.so` shared object is the userland counterpart to the kernel module `XXX` for `iptables`. Looking at `iptables-extensions(8)` on my Fedora 18 (`iptables-1.4.16.2-5.fc18.x86_64`), there is no `random` module for kernel `iptables`, ergo there is none for the userland command either. The configuration for my kernel (`3.8.2-206.fc18.x86_64`) doesn't mention anything resembling RANDOM under the `iptables` configuration section either (all are configured as modules).

I'd guess you've got the `statistic` module wrong (or perhaps you are following an old guide).

**Update:** According to the comments below, I think that what OP wants is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request \
     -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5 -j DROP
```

This is totally untested!

BTW, why do you want do drop half of the pings comming in? Perhaps you should be looking for network testing software?

Comment: see EDIT no 1., I saw above command on internet.
Tell me how can I drop 50 % packets, if above command is not helpful.

Comment: My version of iptables is `iptables v1.3.5` .

Comment: `iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load match statistic:/lib64/iptables/libipt_statistic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` This is the error comes when I run your suggested command.

Comment: I need this functionality to test how it reacts if it faces 50% percent of traffic than original.

Comment: Can you please answer my question? Guide me please, how can I add these two missing files for random and nth patch in IPtables.

Comment: @jhamb, strange. Here (Fedora 18) it works. It is a kernel configuration `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATISTIC`. Check `iptables-extensions(8)` if it is supposed to exist there (the shared file doesn't exist here, BTW).